# Unusual output when trying to Create a blank window in open GL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, glfw

I am trying to create a Blank Window in OpenGL with help of GLFW. below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"learnopengl",NULL,NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"there is a problem with window creation\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window,&width,&height);

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

but when i try to run the above code instead of a black blank it shows an instance of my current screen in newly created window.

Comment: I had the same issue when I first started OpenGL. It boiled down to missing dependencies or having a too old version. I can't remember exactly which one it was, but that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you expect this code to result in a blank window?

As per the spec, the back buffer contents become *undefined* after you swap the buffers (and initially, they are of course undefined too). As a result, the output you should get is also undefined and basically anything might show up.

Add a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` to your render loop if you want some defined output.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but may concern other people and help them, I ran this code and it's working pretty well, but the problem is not in your code, it is your video card driver, so what is happening ?
OpenGL has what is called "The Default Framebuffer", it is the Framebuffer (the buffer contains what you will see) that OpenGL is created with. It is created along with the OpenGL Context. Like Framebuffer Objects, the default framebuffer is a series of images. Unlike FBOs, one of these images usually represents what you actually see on some part of your screen. in other words the default framebuffer is the buffer used by the operating system to render your desktop and other application's windows, so your application is using the default framebuffer as the framebuffer is not edited by your app, so you may need to clear the framebuffer with some other values, let's say colors. this is your code edited with buffer clearing using colors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{

 glfwInit();
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
 window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"learnopengl",NULL,NULL);
 if (window == NULL)
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"there is a problem with window creation\n");
     glfwTerminate();
     return -1;
 }
 glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

 glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
 if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
     return -1;
 }
 int width, height;
 glfwGetFramebufferSize(window,&width,&height);

 glViewport(0,0,width,height);
 
 //this is an added line
 glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); //the RGBA color we will clear with
 
 while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
 {
   glfwPollEvents();
   //this is an added line
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //the buffer used to clear with

   glfwSwapBuffers(window);
 }


  glfwTerminate();
 }
```

Hope this answer and this code help other people who may have this situation.
for further information about the framebuffer check this link : https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers